# Is there a way to stop getting errors with tkinter loops?

Tags: python, tkinter

## Context:

I have been trying to make something like a Fourier transform. I wanted to pretty much replicate the youtuber "The coding train" with his "Coding Challenge #125: Fourier Series" program. I decided to use tkinter because I have no clue what libraries are good, if there is a better one for this kind of thing, please recommend it to me.

## Issue:

I keep getting errors every time I create an infinite loop to make a circle move indefinitely right.

## Code:

My first attempt was as follows:

```py
while True:
    canvas.move(circle, 1, 0)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

This returns an error after exiting the application, though serves the intended purpose. 
I think I may have tried a few more things, but my most recent and desperate attempt to solve this infuriatingly trivial problem was:

```py
async def routine():
        while True:
        canvas.move(circle, 1, 0)
        tk.update()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(routine())
tk.mainloop()
```

## Summary:

This issue does not affect the programs ability to run but is super annoying, furthermore I have read elsewhere that it is best to use the mainloop but I don't know why. Even youtube tutorials I have found do not seem to even acknowledge that their program is spamming their shell. Should I just ignore it or is there a proper way to do this? Also if there is a better way to draw please do share. 
edit:

## Solution:

Per furas answer, I solved this by placing all of my animations into a move function. In the move function is where the circle is told to shift one pixel, then the tk.after() function calls the move function again after however many milliseconds I want. It looks nice enough and works without complaint. 
Example code;

```py
import tkinter

tk = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(tk)
circle = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 100, 100)
def move():
    canvas.move(circle, 1, 0)
    tk.after(100, move)
canvas.pack()
move()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can use `root.after(200, function_name) to run function after 200ms and it can move object and use `root.after(...)` to move object again after 200ms. This way it doesn't stop mainloop which get mouse/key events form system, sends events to widgets, updates widgets, redraw window and widgets and also execute function used in `after(..., function_name)` and in `Button(..., command=function_name)`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is example how to use `after()` to move circle

Function `move()` moves circle and use `root.after(100, move)` to run itself after 100ms again.
This way function loops but it doesn't stops `mainloop`. And it doesn't give error.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def move():
    move_x = random.randint(-5, 5)
    move_y = random.randint(-5, 5)

    canvas.move(circle, move_x, move_y)

    root.after(100, move)

# --- main ---

SIZE = 50
WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500

start_x = random.randint(0, WIDTH-SIZE)
start_y = random.randint(0, HEIGHT-SIZE)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

circle = canvas.create_oval(start_x, start_y, start_x+SIZE, start_y+SIZE, fill='green')

move()

root.mainloop()
```